# I have already installed pycrfsuite still it is giving import error

Tags: python, import, python-crfsuite

I have  already installed pycrfsuite from

```
sudo pip install python-crfsuite
```

but still it is giving import error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "rough.py", line 3, in
>   
> import pycrfsuite ImportError: No module named pycrfsuite

What can i do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are running your program in same python version in which you have installed package

For example,you have installed python-crfsuite in python3 and you are running the code with python2..that might be the case to give the error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. Try to uninstall "python-crfsuite" and install it once again. For me it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You are sure that the python-crfsuite installation imports as pycrfsuite? I cannot think this is anything other than a spelling issue. Just in case, could you show relevant code? Try 'import python-crfsuite'